# Guessing Game for Java (Print Different Statement Loop)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am not sure how to exactly ask my question, but I wanted to print the statement "your first/second/third try" every time the user guesses ( I think what I commented in my code will seem clearer than what I am trying to convey now) but I'm confused on how to do so. also, sorry if my code is messy, I'm a newbie at this lol.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.System;

public class GuessingGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random randGen = new Random();
    int userGuess = 0;
    int userTries = 0;
    int userCompRandom = randGen.nextInt(11)+1;
    String userName = "";
    boolean isWrong = true;
    string guessNumberTag = "";

    System.out.println("Welcome to the number guessing game. What's 
    your name?");
    userName = scnr.nextLine();
    System.out.println("I’m thinking of an integer between 1 and 10. 
    You have 3 guesses.");
    while (isWrong = true){
            userTries +=1;
            userGuess = scnr.nextInt();
            if (userGuess > userCompRandom){
                System.out.println(userGuess);
                System.out.println("Too high, guess lower!");

            }
            else if (userGuess < userCompRandom){
                System.out.println(userGuess); **//First/second/third 
                try: userGuess//**
                System.out.println("Too low, guess higher!");


            }
            else if (userGuess == userCompRandom){
                System.out.println(userGuess);//First/second/third try: userGuess//
                System.out.println("Congratulations " + userName + "! It took you " + userTries + "!");
                break;
            }
      if (userTries>4){
          System.out.println("Game over " +userName + ",you lose!:p");
          break;
      }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: `System.out.printf ("Try number %d%n", ++userTries);`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I actually meant something that would print in words "(first) try" for the first guess and "(second) try" for the second guess.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] guessStatement = {"Your first try.", "Your second try.", "Your third try."};
System.out.println(guessStatement[userTries]);
```

Array index starts at 0, so adjust `userTries`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method to do this.  Note your check is >4 so I added fourth.

```
private static String getPrompt(int tries, int guess) {
    String[] tryWords = { "first", "second", "third", "fourth"} ;
    return String.format("Your %s try: %d", tryWords[tries-1], guess );
}
```

and call it:

```
            System.out.println(getPrompt(userTries, userGuess )); //**First/second/third try: userGuess//**
```